# Adding methods to a class using Groovy in Java

Tags: java, groovy, metaclass

I am working on a Java module that uses Groovy as a compile time dependency and I would like to add a method to my Java class `Person` (Like the [Groovy JDK](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html)) without writing Groovy code.

In Groovy I would achieve it like that

```
Person.meta.doSomething = { String param -> println "do something: ${param}" }
```

How can I do it using the Groovy API form Java?

**EDIT 1:**

I have implemented the following so far and I am almost there. I instantiate an Expando class for `Person` and register a `MethodClosure` that delegates the method call to a method in the class `PersonDefaultMethods`.

```
ExpandoMetaClass expando = new ExpandoMetaClass (Person.class, true, false);
expando.registerInstanceMethod ("format", new MethodClosure (new PersonDefaultMethods(), "format"));
expando.initialize ();
```

The `PersonDefaultMethods` contains the the implementation of the methods I declared in the Expando class.

```
public class PersonDefaultMethods {
   public String format(String format) {
      return this.toString(); // this one gets called
   }

   public String format(Person self, String format) { // but I want this method to be called
      return self.getFirstname() + " " + self.getLastname();
    }
}
```

When I know execute a Groovy script within this context I am able to call the `format` method on a `Person` instance but I am unable to access the `delegate` like I usually can using a closure.

**EDIT 2:**

The approach of using a closure subclass or anonymous closure class fails in my implementation.

```
ExpandoMetaClass expando = new ExpandoMetaClass(Person.class, true, false);
expando.registerInstanceMethod("format", new Closure(this) {

     @Override
     public Object call(Object arguments) {
        return super.call(arguments);
     }

     @Override
     public Class[] getParameterTypes () {
        return new Class[] { String.class};
     }
  });
expando.initialize ();
```

This does the job. Thank you.

Comment: Even if you can get this to work, isn't your code going to end up being a mess of lookups and registry calls?  Java isn't a good fit for this sort of Instance extension.   Hence Groovy

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. The only reason why I try to use this approach is that my company uses Eclipse (w/o Groovy support) and if I start to put Groovy classes into their workspace the project wont build anymore... I am aware that this is a bad situation but I cannot change it (yet).

Comment: re: "unable to access the delegate". In a MethodClosure the delegate/owner is used for the method invocation, here PersonDefaultMethods, so it won't work like this. You will need a Closure subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current meta class via `GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().getMetaClass(Person.class);` better. But to simulate the above you need to do several things by hand Groovy does for you in the background.

- First of all, you will need a `ExpandoMetaClass` (short EMC). If the metaclass from above is not an EMC, you will need to create one and register it in the registry: `ExpandoMetaClass emc = new ExpandoMetaClass(Person.class)`.
- Next you will need to call `registerInstanceMethod` with either a String and Closure, or a MetaMethod. The variant above is the Closure version and will call the other one in the background.
- To follow the Groovy conventions you need to create a Closure subclass (maybe anonymous) with a doCall method of the Signature you want your method be. The String for `registerInstanceMethod` will be the name of the method
- You can of course also leverage one of the existing MetaMethod subclasses (or your own one) to get there.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I applied it but now I run into an exception (see updated question)